# Group Axioms and Closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In this book I am reading, a group is defined as:

A group is an ordered pair $(G,X)$ where $G$ is a set and $X$ is a binary operation on $G$ satisfying the following axioms:

i) $X$ is associative.

ii) $G$ contains an identity.

iii) Each element of $G$ has an inverse.

How does this definition imply that $G$ is closed under this operation?

Comment: It's important that it is implicit in this def'n that each element has a double-sided inverse.That is, with identity 1, for any x in G there exists y with xy=yx=1.

Answer (score 8):

"$X$ is a binary operation on $G$" is a shorthand for "$X$ is a map $G\times G\to G$".

Comment: Oh of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That $G$ is closed in hidden in the sentence "... $X$ is a binary operation on $G$ ..."

Saying this is saying that $X$ maps from $G\times G$ **into** $G$.